# No matching function for call (type&)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

guys!
I got an error while compiling of project

```
LoadConnectorModule.cpp:59:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘LoadConnectorModule::generateFileFoundResponse(char*&, int&, char ( * )[1024], int&)’
         generateFileFoundResponse(dataBuffer, dataLength, &fileName, fd);
                                                                        ^
LoadConnectorModule.cpp:59:72: note: candidate is:
In file included from LoadConnectorModule.cpp:1:0:
LoadConnectorModule.h:16:10: note: void LoadConnectorModule::generateFileFoundResponse(char*, int, char*, int)
     void generateFileFoundResponse(char* dataBuffer, int dataLength, char *fileName, int fd);
```

The function generateFileFoundResponse is called here

```
        char * dataBuffer = NULL;
        char fileName[Utils::default_message_size];
        int dataLength;
        generateFileFoundResponse(dataBuffer, dataLength, &fileName, fd);
```

and is declared as

```
    void generateFileFoundResponse(char* dataBuffer, int dataLength, char *fileName, int fd);
```

And there is the same error for all other methods in this class. Do you have any ide, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileName` parameter is a `char*`, but you pass a `char (*) [1024]` (pointer to array). Just pass the array itself and let it decay to a pointer:

```
generateFileFoundResponse(dataBuffer, dataLength, fileName, fd);
//                                                ^ no &
```

Comment: This helped me. Thank You!:)